# Undefined border display in UWP

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a problem about the display of border in the app UWP:

This is my code:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5">
       <TextBlock x:Name="text" Padding="5"></TextBlock>
</Border>
```

this is the views in my devices:

Lumia 650  dpi:150% windows insider 15014

[image: Lumia 650 dpi:150%]

Tablet 1980x1080 dpi: 150% windows insider 15014

[image: Tablet 1980x1080 dpi: 150%]

Notebook (right visualization) 1440x900 dpi: 100% windows 14393

[image]

I try to change the dpi but is the same result.
What the causes of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. I've logged it in the Feedback Hub [here](https://aka.ms/H2qpti).

I suspect the issue is related to the following (from the [blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/12/01/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14977-mobile/#DKjAp3VJlqr35lsi.97) for build 14977, the first build in which I have noticed this issue):

> We’ve changed the rendering technology used for many types of UWP app content, so please provide feedback through the Feedback Hub if you notice any new visual glitches in UWP apps. ADDED 12/2: For additional context on this change, we are now widely using the same Windows.UI.Composition API that app developers have access to for XAML UWP app and shell rendering.

Comment: is it a bug of winsows Insider build ?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer with additional info about the issue.